# Make brand stand same line as collapse button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my brand logo to stand same line, as my collapse button. But i wont work, it keeps going under like on the picture. [image]

I've tryed adding `float left` to the button, and `float right` to the brand, but luck. I've also tried going in my f12 and disable, everything that has a padding or margin, still without luck. How can this be fixed?

My navigation code is this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#forside">Forside</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#cocktails">Cocktails</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#omos">Om os</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#priser">Priser</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
            <img id="NavLogo" src="../Content/images/NavLogo.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I'v read that i should use Pull, but as of my knowledge that's for bootstrap3, and i'm using 4, but arn't pull the same as float in the end?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "row" and "col" to layout the content

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#forside">Forside</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#cocktails">Cocktails</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#omos">Om os</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#priser">Priser</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
                <img id="NavLogo" src="../Content/images/NavLogo.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check Bootstrap Grid System at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/